# Angular using InnerHTML to determine href or routerLink

Tags: javascript, html, angular, multidimensional-array, strapi

Currently solving a problem where I receive a link from a CMS. This can either be internal or external to my Angular app. I've built logic to determine if that link is external or internal and build an html string appropriately. ex:

```
// if external return:
    `[href]=${this.link}`
  
// if internal return:
    `[routerLink]=[${this.link}]`
```

Then I pass that HTML string into my anchor tag in the template using `[innerHtml]=`.

Unfortunately, instead of the anchor tag receiving the HTML string as an attribute, the page simply renders the HTML string as text on the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to create two anchor tags depending on the link type.

```
<a *ngIf="extern" [routerLink]="link"></a>
<a *ngIf="!extern" [href]="link"></a>
```